# A therewith equivalent (in the 'with that' sense) for people (basically a 'with them'

Tags: lexicon

Taking the cue from the [Cambridge Dictionary's "Therewith" example sentence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/therewith):

*I can truly say that in the three years during which you have managed this store, I remember no single complaint against you in connection therewith.*

I would like to know if exist a word equivalent to therewith with the meaning of 'with them' instead of 'with that'.

Say:

*From all the people I listened to during the meeting, I remember no single complaint against you in connection **[WORD]**.*

Does exist a "therewith word" that can be used here instead of saying "with them'?

Comment: _Therewith_ doesn't mean _with them_. It means _with it_, and it refers almost exclusively to abstractions like clauses and phrases and the events and states they describe.

Comment: All you'd need is *in that connection*.

Comment: Or simply “From all the people I listened to during the meeting, I remember no single complaint against you.”  Or “… against you from any of them.”

Comment: Maybe you could use *therefrom*.  I personally strongly dislike that style, e.g. "holds the copyright thereto" in some of my audiobooks.